# If/else conditional based on character count jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a jQuery function that counts the character length of each anchor tag & applies a class if the character count is greater than "5". Additionally, if the character count is greater than 7 (4 + 3) then apply a different class.

This is where I got to (JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/2mg3q/):

**HTML**

```
<div id="global-nav">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item with11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#nav li a{
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}

#nav li a.TEST1{
    border-color:red;
}

#nav li a.TEST2{
    border-color:blue;
}
```

**JS**

```
var navChars = 4;

$('#global-nav #nav li a').filter(function() {

    if($(this).text().length > navChars){
        $('#global-nav #nav li a').addClass('TEST1');

    }else if($(this).text().length > navChars + 3){
        $('#global-nav #nav li a').addClass('TEST2');
    }

});
```

Without the "else" statement, both TEST1 & TEST2 classes were being applied to the anchor tags. With the else statement, only TEST1 is applied to the anchor tags.

The original JS I was using & that I have based the above on worked great for a singular condition but now I need to accommodate for at least 2 possible character lengths.

Original JS that I have altered (hacked):

```
var navChars = 13;

$('#global-nav #nav li a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().length > navChars;
}).addClass('navMultiLine');
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2mg3q/9/ Check this fiddle

Comment: @dan you want `TEST1` to be applied on `a` having length greater than 4 or to both 4 and (4+3)?

Comment: If the length is greater than 5 apply TEST1, if it is greater than 7 only apply class TEST2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
<div id="#global-nav">
```

with

```
<div id="global-nav">
```

Try:

```
$('#global-nav #nav li').each(function() {
    var len = $(this).find("a").text().length;    
    if(len > 7){
        $(this).find("a").addClass("TEST2");
    }
    else if(len > 4){
        $(this).find("a").addClass("TEST1");
    }
});
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2mg3q/6/)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear with the specifics of my question. As mentioned above: If the length is greater than 5 apply TEST1, if it is greater than 7 only apply class TEST2

Comment: @Hiral - thanks so much, it works great! Nice & clean solution!

Answer (score 2):

`id` should not start with `#`

```
<div id="global-nav">
```

then

```
$('#global-nav #nav li a').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        length = $.trim($this.text()).length;
    if (length > navChars + 3) {
        $this.addClass('TEST2');
    } else if (length > navChars) {
        $this.addClass('TEST1');
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f8f4F/)

Comment: Hi @Arun, thanks for your answer. I'm a little confused by your opening line though - you say the ID shouldn't start with # but then in your answer you have used "#"

Comment: @Dan ID in the *HTML* (`<div id="global-nav">`). jQuery selectors are a different thing.

Comment: @Dan that is in the id selector, in your fiddle the `div` elements id attribute value is starting with `#`

Comment: @Dan Did you check the attached fiddle.... also can you clarify the need for the additional class ie if the length is 8 then whether both test1 and test2 classes need to be applied

Comment: Ohhhh I see it - hahah - not sure how I missed that (long day!). Thanks for the heads up. That worked really well but I did notice that both the classes are added to the anchor tag that the else condition affects: http://screencast.com/t/yLi7P4p0e Is there a way to have only one class applied?

Comment: @Arun, you appear to have lost your navChars variable

Answer (score 1):

When the condition is 
FIRST - if > 4
SECOND - if > 7
then the second gets never hit..
You should change the order to:
FIRST - if > 7
SECOND -if > 4

Comment: @ArunPJohny That's unlikely. Both classes only change the border color so there's no reason to have them both.

Comment: @Juhana from the comments of the OP that is what is required

Comment: @ArunPJohny *"Without the "else" statement, both TEST1 & TEST2 classes were being applied"* sounds like he *didn't* want that to happen.

Comment: That's 100% correct @Juhana. Sorry if I was unclear. Thanks everyone for the fantastic support - there are so many great answers & solutions!

Answer (score 1):

The single-line filter does not work, because it will apply the class only for those objects, for which the condition is true.

Also, mind the order of conditions, it's crucial here! (Longest lengths first!)

Try this:

```
$('#global-nav #nav li a').each(function() {
    // save this jQuery-obj & it's length, for better performance!
    var $obj = $(this);
    var charLen = $obj.text().length;
    // mind the order of conditions! longest lengths first!
    if (charLen > navChars + X) {
        $obj.addClass('TestX');
    }
    else if (charLen > navChars + 3) {
        $obj.addClass('Test2');
    }
    else if (charLen > navChars) {
        $obj.addClass('Test1');
    }
});
```

Comment: I want the class to be added to all items that the condition applies to. So all a tags with a character count greater than 5 should get TEST1 & all a tag items with a character count greater than 7 should get the class of TEST2 (only - as in not both the classes)

Comment: I see, I forgot the "else" in one branch (by mistakte). Fixed that. Apart from that, it does what you want. Only apply *one* of the classes, right? Never more than one. You see, the order of conditions is crucial here!

Answer (score 1):

```
var navChars = 4;

$('#global-nav #nav li a').filter(function() {

//bigger than 4 but smaller than 7
if($(this).text().length > navChars && $(this).text().length < 7){
    $('#global-nav #nav li a').addClass('TEST1');

}
//bigger than 7 
if($(this).text().length > navChars+3){
    $('#global-nav #nav li a').addClass('TEST2');
}

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `$('#global-nav #nav li a').addClass('TEST1');` adds the TEST1 class to **ALL** links inside a li inside a #nav inside a #global-nav.  In order to just apply the class to the current element you should use $(this).addClass('TEST1').  Also, you should use .each() to iterate over the elements instead of .filter().

Also, @Arun was referring to the id in the HTML, not in the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution with an each loop. You made probably a typo by using #global-nav in your HTML instead of id="gobal-nav"

The fiddle could be found at http://jsfiddle.net/3DU9t/

```
var navChars = 4;

$('#global-nav #nav a').each(function() {

    if($(this).html().length > navChars + 3){

        $(this).addClass('TEST2');

    } else {

        if($(this).html().length > navChars){
            $(this).addClass('TEST1');

        }

    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer @osi - it worked really well. I wish I could mark the solutions that worked as correct! Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, helping someone is more worth than the points earned for a marked solution.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the else statement and remove the Test1 class for the second condition.

```
var navChars = 4;

$('#global-nav #nav li a').filter(function() {

    if($(this).text().length > navChars){
        $('#global-nav #nav li a').addClass('TEST1');

    }
    if($(this).text().length > navChars + 3){
        $('#global-nav #nav li a').removeClass('TEST1');
        $('#global-nav #nav li a').addClass('TEST2');
    }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var navChars = 4;

$('#global-nav #nav li a').filter(function() {

    if($(this).text().length > navChars){
        $('#global-nav #nav li a').addClass('TEST1');

    }else if($(this).text().length > Number(navChars + 3)){
        $('#global-nav #nav li a').addClass('TEST2');
    }

});
```