# Long words overflow flex container

Tags: css, flexbox, word-wrap

Does anyone know how to avoid overflowing of long words in flex container?

```css
.wrap{
  display:flex;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="a">
    a
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
  </div>
</div>
```

I only found this thread [Break long words inside flex item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49943630/break-long-words-inside-flex-item) but it doesn't solve the problem

Thank you

Comment: What do you want it to look like? overflow:hidden?

Comment: you can break the line with word-break: break-all

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: add `min-width:0` to `b`

Comment: I don't want neither overflow: hidden nor word-break: break-all. I need to make a new line when the long word "ffff..." hits the end of its ".wrap" container which shouldn't be wider than 100% (max-width:100%). But I don't want to accomplish this by "break-all" because this property crops not only long words but even short words.

Comment: Thank you Temani Afif. That solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

### Nice and Easy - word-break: break-all;

Just add this. Nothing more nothing less :)

```
word-break: break-all;
```

[image]

**See the result here:**

```css
.wrap{
  display:flex;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  max-width:100%;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="a">
    a
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But break-all will break even shorter words...change "ffff" to for example "animals animals" (x100) and the end of line will look like "ani" or "anima" and so on.

Comment: Yes. There is no word length variable. However, you could write some JavaScript to first count how many letters a work has, then if the condition is met, say 20 letters, it would then insert the `word-break: break-all;` style.

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345070/if-else-conditional-based-on-character-count-jquery

Comment: Ok, thanks, but I need to solve this ideally without JS. I create new thread which describes my problem better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52277368/flexbox-affects-overflow-wrap-behavior

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do like this?

```
 .wrap{
      display: flex;
      max-width: 150px;
    }

    .b{
      word-break: break-all;
    }
```