# Flexbox affects overflow-wrap behavior

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

Look at this snippet. This is how the `overflow-wrap: break-word` should work:

```css
.wrap{
   overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="a">
    first div
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal 
  </div>
</div>
```

And now see how change its behavior in combination with `display:flex`:

```css
.wrap{
   overflow-wrap: break-word;
   display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="a">
    first div
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal 
  </div>
</div>
```

How to edit the second snippet to not showing horizontal scrollbar? (Without use of overflow: hidden)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you give `display: flex` to the `wrap`, by default the elements `a` and `b` are *flexed* in a line.

Now another default of a *flexbox child* is the `min-width` property is *auto* by default and so the elements `a` and `b` takes a `min-width` corresponding to its content. So set `min-width: 0` and things go back to *normal* - see demo below:

```css
.wrap {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  display: flex;
}

.b {
  min-width: 0; /* ADDED */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="a">
    first div
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
    animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal
    animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal animal
  </div>
</div>
```