# Why does my right hand flex column suddenly drop below a left column?

Tags: css, html, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Why does my right hand flex column suddenly drop below a left column when (fluid) content is added?

I want a fixed width left column and a right hand column containing an image slider ([Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/)).

The column layout works fine when empty, but as soon as I add the image slider, the column jumps to 100% width and drops below the fixed column.  This is odd as the slider is responsive and shouldn't expand beyond it's container - it's not fixed width.

**Please see this codepen:** https://codepen.io/nick-gilbert/pen/wORaOP

My basic column layout is very simple:

```
<div class="row">

   <div class="col search-sidebar">
      left
   </div>

   <div class="col">
      right
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.search-sidebar: {
  flex: 0 0 260px;
}
```

Here's an image showing the problem (but better to look at the codepen):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `flex-nowrap` class on the row element.

By default row is flex-wrap:wrap, so when content gets bigger than the width the divs stack up. To avoid them stacking up , use `flex-nowrap` class of bootstrap.

See the updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LaMpLb)

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:40px;">
    <div class="col search-sidebar" style="background-color:aquamarine">left</div>

    <div class="col" style="margin-bottom:20px;background-color:pink">right<br /> (works when empty)
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row flex-nowrap">

    <div class="col search-sidebar" style="background-color:aquamarine">
      left<br><br>
    </div>

    <div class="col" style="margin-bottom:20px;background-color:pink">
      right<br />Broken when an Image slider loads. This should stay to the right of the green column.
      <br />

      <!--  Demos -->
      <div id="imageCarousel">
        <div id="imageThumbnails" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

          <div class="sliderThumb rounded">
            <a class="galleryLink" rel="Group" href='#'>
                            <img src='http://placehold.it/160x160' width="175" height="175" />
                        </a>
          </div>

          <div class="sliderThumb rounded">
            <a class="galleryLink" rel="Group" href='#'>
                            <img src='http://placehold.it/160x160' width="175" height="175"  />
                        </a>
          </div>
          <div class="sliderThumb rounded">
            <a class="galleryLink" rel="Group" href='#'>
                            <img src='http://placehold.it/160x160' width="175" height="175" />
                        </a>
          </div>

          <div class="sliderThumb rounded">
            <a class="galleryLink" rel="Group" href='#'>
                            <img src='http://placehold.it/160x160' width="175" height="175"  />
                        </a>
          </div>
          <div class="sliderThumb rounded">
            <a class="galleryLink" rel="Group" href='#'>
                            <img src='http://placehold.it/160x160' width="175" height="175" />
                        </a>
          </div>

          <div class="sliderThumb rounded">
            <a class="galleryLink" rel="Group" href='#'>
                            <img src='http://placehold.it/160x160' width="175" height="175"  />
                        </a>
          </div>
          <div class="sliderThumb rounded">
            <a class="galleryLink" rel="Group" href='#'>
                            <img src='http://placehold.it/160x160' width="175" height="175" />
                        </a>
          </div>

          <div class="sliderThumb rounded">
            <a class="galleryLink" rel="Group" href='#'>
                            <img src='http://placehold.it/160x160' width="175" height="175"  />
                        </a>
          </div>
          <div class="sliderThumb rounded">
            <a class="galleryLink" rel="Group" href='#'>
                            <img src='http://placehold.it/160x160' width="175" height="175" />
                        </a>
          </div>

          <div class="sliderThumb rounded">
            <a class="galleryLink" rel="Group" href='#'>
                            <img src='http://placehold.it/160x160' width="175" height="175"  />
                        </a>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- end row -->

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  The demo works fine now, but unfortunately my real-world problem has a new issue, in that the flex column is still too wide: http://venuefinder.staging.x-rm.com/   (pink column shouldn't be that wide)

Comment: Let me check and get back to you

Comment: Updated pen showing the problem: https://codepen.io/nick-gilbert/pen/aMPdzW

Comment: Somehow, the flex column is still the width of the entire container, instead of sizing to fit the gap to the right of the green column. Red background is the container.

Comment: Yeah i get whats happening. I am trying to figure out why its happening. Can you try removing the carousel and check if the width issue stil persists

Comment: add `min-width:0` to your `col` containing the owl carousel, to see *why* see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52277368/flexbox-affects-overflow-wrap-behavior/52278099#52278099) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size)

Comment: Yeah it doesn't... without the carousel it works fine.  Something inside the carousel is probably trying to jump to the wrong width.

Comment: @kukkuz Doesn't seem to help?

Comment: I guess what @kukkuz said makes sense. You can go with it. I tried and it worked for me

Comment: Sorry - "user error" on my side. It's working now!   Thank you both very much!