# Flexbox resize and scrollable overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have content that I am resizing, and I want to have a fixed heading that doesn't grow/shrink and is not part of the scrollable content. With the content below becoming scrollable if there is not enough space.

The content outer wrapper (`flexGrowWrapper`) has a `flex-grow: 1` and the inner wrapper has `height: 100%; overflow-y: auto`. The thought process here is that `flexGrowWrapper` will fill up any remaining space within the `resize` div, the inner wrapper will then take the full height of the `flexGrowWrapper` and if there is overflow, it should scroll.

What is happening is that `flexGrowWrapper` does grow to fill the `resize` area, but it seems that it's content is dictating it's min-height.

How can I make `flexGrowWrapper` never go beyond the `resize` area height?

```js
$("button").click(function() {
 $(".resize").toggleClass("small");
});
```

```css
.resize {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 300px;
}

.resize.small {
  height: 100px;
}

.heading {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.flexGrowWrapper {
  border: 2px solid red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<button>
Resize
</button>
<div class="resize">
  <div class="heading">
  <label>Some heading that wont scroll</label>
  </div>
  <div class="flexGrowWrapper">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content">
        content
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        content
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        content
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        content
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        content
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        content
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
 Something else here
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note: I looked at the [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515042/scrolling-a-flexbox-with-overflowing-content), but it seems to have some differences, and I couldn't get the solutions to work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `min-height: 0` to `.flexGrowWrapper` - see demo below:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $(".resize").toggleClass("small");
});
```

```css
.resize {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 300px;
}

.resize.small {
  height: 100px;
}

.heading {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.flexGrowWrapper {
  border: 2px solid red;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 0; /* ADDED */
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<button>
Resize
</button>
<div class="resize">
  <div class="heading">
    <label>Some heading that wont scroll</label>
  </div>
  <div class="flexGrowWrapper">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content">
        content
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        content
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        content
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        content
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        content
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        content
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  Something else here
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Why this works**

Note that this is because for a *column flexbox* the default `min-height` value is `auto` (along the *flex axis*). You can see some examples of this behaviour below:

- [Flexbox affects overflow-wrap behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52277368/flexbox-affects-overflow-wrap-behavior/52278099#52278099)
- [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size)