# How to extend a <div> to fill its parent, without expanding according to its own content?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

**Context**

I'm making a website that allows to create csgo bind/config files, so I splited the page in half : on the left, inputs from user, on the right, the configuration result.
I have one button, at the end of the each panel, to compute inputs and to download the file, but I would like to keep them visible all time (currently, they are at the bottom of the page, i need to scroll to find them).

For one panel, we have :

[image: example]

As the title and the button have "known" position, is there a way to extend the *lorem ipsum* div, pushing the button to the bottom of the panel, without overflowing the screen ?
I don't want to use absolute attributes, in anticipation of an adaptation for smaller screens (at that time, the two panels will be located one below the other).

I have try some stuff with `flex-grow`, nothing convincing.

---

I don't have any defined height for the *lorem ipsum* div; I want to cover the maximum of the panel, without overflowing it.

Here is some simplified code :

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

#wrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.panel {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 50%;
  padding: 1em;
}

#lorem {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


/* add colors :) */

body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#left {
  background-color: red;
}

#right {
  background-color: purple;
}

#lorem {
  background: yellow;
}

#wrapper {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
}

h2 {
  background-color: green;
}

input[type=button] {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="panel" id="left">
    <div id="title">
      <h2>Plic</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="lorem">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec viverra ante sit amet velit rutrum eleifend. Integer efficitur convallis dui, in aliquet augue pellentesque ut. Aenean ut lobortis nibh. Nullam et laoreet arcu, sed consectetur lectus.
        Phasellus ut nunc orci. Fusce mauris neque, ullamcorper at auctor vel, mollis vitae dolor. Mauris eget eleifend dui. Donec ut vestibulum ex. Nullam laoreet mi ut augue posuere pellentesque. Curabitur aliquet rutrum leo iaculis aliquet. Donec convallis
        ante nunc, nec dictum ex fringilla sit amet.</p>
      <p>Nam vel lacus non leo auctor ornare. Integer sit amet lectus in elit tristique eleifend ut a libero. Nam eu mauris in sapien semper venenatis. Integer malesuada fringilla sapien vel blandit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
        Nulla pretium sem quis nulla efficitur fermentum. Vestibulum leo nisi, imperdiet ut venenatis sed, consectetur cursus purus. Morbi ac ipsum aliquet, tempor enim bibendum, cursus mi. Phasellus eget semper augue, ut viverra tellus. Nulla lacus nisi,
        congue imperdiet imperdiet sed, sollicitudin eu ex. Ut non dapibus elit. Donec at mollis ante. In aliquet pulvinar sollicitudin. Duis ac orci lobortis, pellentesque lacus in, feugiat urna. Suspendisse consectetur, risus ac elementum condimentum,
        velit diam convallis ex, id ornare leo arcu at sapien.</p>
      <p>Donec bibendum elit id orci rutrum, at eleifend urna porttitor. Vivamus odio quam, gravida at euismod in, vestibulum et dui. Morbi egestas urna eu erat hendrerit, in porttitor libero pharetra. Integer justo mauris, pulvinar tincidunt turpis a, tristique
        ullamcorper nisi. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin mollis tincidunt nunc eget tempor. Mauris bibendum pretium quam id pretium.</p>
      <p>Phasellus quis nisi vehicula, viverra lacus non, porttitor dui. Suspendisse fringilla ullamcorper finibus. Praesent nec auctor elit. Nulla sit amet risus egestas, lacinia orci feugiat, imperdiet metus. Morbi purus metus, egestas eu massa in, aliquet
        ullamcorper lectus. Praesent condimentum vehicula condimentum. Morbi nec neque a massa egestas tempus. Donec a cursus dui. Nullam scelerisque ultricies odio a dictum. Proin at ullamcorper justo, non auctor justo. Morbi id nunc id augue pulvinar
        porttitor. Vestibulum congue magna eu odio condimentum rutrum. Pellentesque non pretium nibh.</p>
      <p>Nunc ante leo, dapibus sit amet felis id, mattis auctor nisi. Praesent nec lacus posuere, commodo orci in, varius purus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus in euismod nibh, nec congue purus. Aenean euismod laoreet
        eros, et iaculis mi pharetra vitae. Curabitur eget massa non nibh consectetur pellentesque. In varius pharetra urna, ac tristique sapien lobortis vel.</p>
      <p>Quisque eu velit mauris. Nunc sit amet placerat tellus. Praesent in fermentum orci. Sed pulvinar facilisis ornare. Vestibulum et metus eget libero tristique vulputate vitae vitae justo. Duis sit amet malesuada dolor. Etiam semper purus id turpis
        ultrices, eu facilisis purus varius. Vivamus interdum elit ligula, eget condimentum purus tincidunt ac. Nullam at mattis arcu. Nunc vitae mi consequat, hendrerit urna et, gravida nulla. Ut ac purus blandit, volutpat leo non, facilisis lorem. Vestibulum
        ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi dignissim porttitor sem et auctor. Praesent rutrum dignissim orci sit amet euismod.</p>
      <p>Pellentesque hendrerit, arcu a iaculis semper, nisi libero porta turpis, et suscipit velit ipsum eu eros. Integer ex elit, pretium vel sapien eget, pulvinar sagittis tellus. Etiam non finibus ante, vitae viverra sem. Nulla in purus in lectus varius
        pulvinar quis non turpis. Suspendisse sit amet arcu orci. Aliquam erat volutpat. Cras tincidunt enim vitae aliquam commodo. Curabitur non justo viverra, porttitor lorem sed, viverra diam.</p>
      <p>Etiam et lobortis quam. Etiam accumsan pharetra lorem, nec sagittis leo vestibulum nec. Aenean pulvinar nisl ac sapien ultricies, eget lacinia neque aliquet. Fusce egestas libero id nisl rutrum, eget egestas turpis interdum. Etiam consectetur convallis
        ex. Pellentesque mollis tortor vel dapibus tincidunt. Phasellus varius, nibh non consequat rhoncus, nisi est mollis quam, sed lacinia risus nisl sit amet arcu. Donec id tellus eu justo rutrum dictum. Integer tristique risus ut odio rutrum, quis
        dignissim est varius. Cras a tortor semper, accumsan urna sed, mattis dolor. Ut eget placerat purus. Aliquam in sollicitudin tellus. Vestibulum a semper quam, ut hendrerit enim.</p>
      <p>Sed et erat consequat, ultrices est quis, sollicitudin lectus. Sed eu semper sapien. Sed suscipit bibendum lacus in semper. Duis mi tellus, gravida a risus id, bibendum tincidunt lectus. Nam consectetur iaculis tempus. Phasellus id consequat felis.
        Aenean at ipsum molestie, ornare dui in, mollis turpis. Suspendisse sagittis in sapien ac consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="button">
      <input type="button" value="Press Me">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel" id="right">
    <div>
      <h2>Ploc</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Press Me">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look into `vh` units. See [this answer to a similar "100% height" question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16837667/215552).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make each of you `panel` elements a *column flexbox* with `height: 100%` (also consider `border-box` to including `padding` in `height`).

Now just add `min-height: 0` to `wrapper` element - see demo below:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

#wrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 0; /* added */
}

.panel {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 50%;
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex; /* added */
  height: 100%; /* added */
  flex-direction: column; /* added */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* added */
}

#lorem {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


/* add colors :) */

body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#left {
  background-color: red;
}

#right {
  background-color: purple;
}

#lorem {
  background: yellow;
}

#wrapper {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
}

h2 {
  background-color: green;
}

input[type=button] {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="panel" id="left">
    <div id="title">
      <h2>Plic</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="lorem">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec viverra ante sit amet velit rutrum eleifend. Integer efficitur convallis dui, in aliquet augue pellentesque ut. Aenean ut lobortis nibh. Nullam et laoreet arcu, sed consectetur lectus.
        Phasellus ut nunc orci. Fusce mauris neque, ullamcorper at auctor vel, mollis vitae dolor. Mauris eget eleifend dui. Donec ut vestibulum ex. Nullam laoreet mi ut augue posuere pellentesque. Curabitur aliquet rutrum leo iaculis aliquet. Donec convallis
        ante nunc, nec dictum ex fringilla sit amet.</p>
      <p>Nam vel lacus non leo auctor ornare. Integer sit amet lectus in elit tristique eleifend ut a libero. Nam eu mauris in sapien semper venenatis. Integer malesuada fringilla sapien vel blandit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
        Nulla pretium sem quis nulla efficitur fermentum. Vestibulum leo nisi, imperdiet ut venenatis sed, consectetur cursus purus. Morbi ac ipsum aliquet, tempor enim bibendum, cursus mi. Phasellus eget semper augue, ut viverra tellus. Nulla lacus nisi,
        congue imperdiet imperdiet sed, sollicitudin eu ex. Ut non dapibus elit. Donec at mollis ante. In aliquet pulvinar sollicitudin. Duis ac orci lobortis, pellentesque lacus in, feugiat urna. Suspendisse consectetur, risus ac elementum condimentum,
        velit diam convallis ex, id ornare leo arcu at sapien.</p>
      <p>Donec bibendum elit id orci rutrum, at eleifend urna porttitor. Vivamus odio quam, gravida at euismod in, vestibulum et dui. Morbi egestas urna eu erat hendrerit, in porttitor libero pharetra. Integer justo mauris, pulvinar tincidunt turpis a, tristique
        ullamcorper nisi. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin mollis tincidunt nunc eget tempor. Mauris bibendum pretium quam id pretium.</p>
      <p>Phasellus quis nisi vehicula, viverra lacus non, porttitor dui. Suspendisse fringilla ullamcorper finibus. Praesent nec auctor elit. Nulla sit amet risus egestas, lacinia orci feugiat, imperdiet metus. Morbi purus metus, egestas eu massa in, aliquet
        ullamcorper lectus. Praesent condimentum vehicula condimentum. Morbi nec neque a massa egestas tempus. Donec a cursus dui. Nullam scelerisque ultricies odio a dictum. Proin at ullamcorper justo, non auctor justo. Morbi id nunc id augue pulvinar
        porttitor. Vestibulum congue magna eu odio condimentum rutrum. Pellentesque non pretium nibh.</p>
      <p>Nunc ante leo, dapibus sit amet felis id, mattis auctor nisi. Praesent nec lacus posuere, commodo orci in, varius purus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus in euismod nibh, nec congue purus. Aenean euismod laoreet
        eros, et iaculis mi pharetra vitae. Curabitur eget massa non nibh consectetur pellentesque. In varius pharetra urna, ac tristique sapien lobortis vel.</p>
      <p>Quisque eu velit mauris. Nunc sit amet placerat tellus. Praesent in fermentum orci. Sed pulvinar facilisis ornare. Vestibulum et metus eget libero tristique vulputate vitae vitae justo. Duis sit amet malesuada dolor. Etiam semper purus id turpis
        ultrices, eu facilisis purus varius. Vivamus interdum elit ligula, eget condimentum purus tincidunt ac. Nullam at mattis arcu. Nunc vitae mi consequat, hendrerit urna et, gravida nulla. Ut ac purus blandit, volutpat leo non, facilisis lorem. Vestibulum
        ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi dignissim porttitor sem et auctor. Praesent rutrum dignissim orci sit amet euismod.</p>
      <p>Pellentesque hendrerit, arcu a iaculis semper, nisi libero porta turpis, et suscipit velit ipsum eu eros. Integer ex elit, pretium vel sapien eget, pulvinar sagittis tellus. Etiam non finibus ante, vitae viverra sem. Nulla in purus in lectus varius
        pulvinar quis non turpis. Suspendisse sit amet arcu orci. Aliquam erat volutpat. Cras tincidunt enim vitae aliquam commodo. Curabitur non justo viverra, porttitor lorem sed, viverra diam.</p>
      <p>Etiam et lobortis quam. Etiam accumsan pharetra lorem, nec sagittis leo vestibulum nec. Aenean pulvinar nisl ac sapien ultricies, eget lacinia neque aliquet. Fusce egestas libero id nisl rutrum, eget egestas turpis interdum. Etiam consectetur convallis
        ex. Pellentesque mollis tortor vel dapibus tincidunt. Phasellus varius, nibh non consequat rhoncus, nisi est mollis quam, sed lacinia risus nisl sit amet arcu. Donec id tellus eu justo rutrum dictum. Integer tristique risus ut odio rutrum, quis
        dignissim est varius. Cras a tortor semper, accumsan urna sed, mattis dolor. Ut eget placerat purus. Aliquam in sollicitudin tellus. Vestibulum a semper quam, ut hendrerit enim.</p>
      <p>Sed et erat consequat, ultrices est quis, sollicitudin lectus. Sed eu semper sapien. Sed suscipit bibendum lacus in semper. Duis mi tellus, gravida a risus id, bibendum tincidunt lectus. Nam consectetur iaculis tempus. Phasellus id consequat felis.
        Aenean at ipsum molestie, ornare dui in, mollis turpis. Suspendisse sagittis in sapien ac consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="button">
      <input type="button" value="Press Me">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel" id="right">
    <div>
      <h2>Ploc</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Press Me">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

PS: Adding `min-height: 0` is to *override* the default `min-height: auto` for *flex items* in column direction - you can see some examples of this:

- [Flexbox affects overflow-wrap behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52277368/flexbox-affects-overflow-wrap-behavior/52278099#52278099)
- [Flexbox resize and scrollable overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55303538/flexbox-resize-and-scrollable-overflow/55303600#55303600)
- [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size)

Answer (score 0):

Added the following CSS to your `lorem id`:

```
#lorem {
  height: 80%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Also to your `panel`: `max-height: 100%`;

Key part here is `overflow-y: scroll`. This works as long as you have a `height` defined. Since you want the content of your `lorem` to be relative to your panel, you can use a `%` height, in this case 80% seems to fit nicely between your title and button.

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}

#lorem {
  height: 80%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#wrapper {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.panel {
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-height: 100%;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 50%;
    padding: 1em;
}


/* add colors :) */
body {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

#left {
    background-color: red;
}

#right {
    background-color: purple;
}

#lorem {
    background: yellow;
}

#wrapper {
    background-color: darkblue;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}

h2 {
    background-color: green;
}

input[type=button] {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="panel" id="left">
                <div id="title">
                    <h2>Plic</h2>
                </div>
                <div id="lorem">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec viverra ante sit amet velit rutrum eleifend. Integer efficitur convallis dui, in aliquet augue pellentesque ut. Aenean ut lobortis nibh. Nullam et laoreet arcu, sed consectetur lectus. Phasellus ut nunc orci. Fusce mauris neque, ullamcorper at auctor vel, mollis vitae dolor. Mauris eget eleifend dui. Donec ut vestibulum ex. Nullam laoreet mi ut augue posuere pellentesque. Curabitur aliquet rutrum leo iaculis aliquet. Donec convallis ante nunc, nec dictum ex fringilla sit amet.</p>
                    <p>Nam vel lacus non leo auctor ornare. Integer sit amet lectus in elit tristique eleifend ut a libero. Nam eu mauris in sapien semper venenatis. Integer malesuada fringilla sapien vel blandit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla pretium sem quis nulla efficitur fermentum. Vestibulum leo nisi, imperdiet ut venenatis sed, consectetur cursus purus. Morbi ac ipsum aliquet, tempor enim bibendum, cursus mi. Phasellus eget semper augue, ut viverra tellus. Nulla lacus nisi, congue imperdiet imperdiet sed, sollicitudin eu ex. Ut non dapibus elit. Donec at mollis ante. In aliquet pulvinar sollicitudin. Duis ac orci lobortis, pellentesque lacus in, feugiat urna. Suspendisse consectetur, risus ac elementum condimentum, velit diam convallis ex, id ornare leo arcu at sapien.</p>
                    <p>Donec bibendum elit id orci rutrum, at eleifend urna porttitor. Vivamus odio quam, gravida at euismod in, vestibulum et dui. Morbi egestas urna eu erat hendrerit, in porttitor libero pharetra. Integer justo mauris, pulvinar tincidunt turpis a, tristique ullamcorper nisi. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin mollis tincidunt nunc eget tempor. Mauris bibendum pretium quam id pretium.</p>
                    <p>Phasellus quis nisi vehicula, viverra lacus non, porttitor dui. Suspendisse fringilla ullamcorper finibus. Praesent nec auctor elit. Nulla sit amet risus egestas, lacinia orci feugiat, imperdiet metus. Morbi purus metus, egestas eu massa in, aliquet ullamcorper lectus. Praesent condimentum vehicula condimentum. Morbi nec neque a massa egestas tempus. Donec a cursus dui. Nullam scelerisque ultricies odio a dictum. Proin at ullamcorper justo, non auctor justo. Morbi id nunc id augue pulvinar porttitor. Vestibulum congue magna eu odio condimentum rutrum. Pellentesque non pretium nibh.</p>
                    <p>Nunc ante leo, dapibus sit amet felis id, mattis auctor nisi. Praesent nec lacus posuere, commodo orci in, varius purus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus in euismod nibh, nec congue purus. Aenean euismod laoreet eros, et iaculis mi pharetra vitae. Curabitur eget massa non nibh consectetur pellentesque. In varius pharetra urna, ac tristique sapien lobortis vel.</p>
                    <p>Quisque eu velit mauris. Nunc sit amet placerat tellus. Praesent in fermentum orci. Sed pulvinar facilisis ornare. Vestibulum et metus eget libero tristique vulputate vitae vitae justo. Duis sit amet malesuada dolor. Etiam semper purus id turpis ultrices, eu facilisis purus varius. Vivamus interdum elit ligula, eget condimentum purus tincidunt ac. Nullam at mattis arcu. Nunc vitae mi consequat, hendrerit urna et, gravida nulla. Ut ac purus blandit, volutpat leo non, facilisis lorem. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi dignissim porttitor sem et auctor. Praesent rutrum dignissim orci sit amet euismod.</p>
                    <p>Pellentesque hendrerit, arcu a iaculis semper, nisi libero porta turpis, et suscipit velit ipsum eu eros. Integer ex elit, pretium vel sapien eget, pulvinar sagittis tellus. Etiam non finibus ante, vitae viverra sem. Nulla in purus in lectus varius pulvinar quis non turpis. Suspendisse sit amet arcu orci. Aliquam erat volutpat. Cras tincidunt enim vitae aliquam commodo. Curabitur non justo viverra, porttitor lorem sed, viverra diam.</p>
                    <p>Etiam et lobortis quam. Etiam accumsan pharetra lorem, nec sagittis leo vestibulum nec. Aenean pulvinar nisl ac sapien ultricies, eget lacinia neque aliquet. Fusce egestas libero id nisl rutrum, eget egestas turpis interdum. Etiam consectetur convallis ex. Pellentesque mollis tortor vel dapibus tincidunt. Phasellus varius, nibh non consequat rhoncus, nisi est mollis quam, sed lacinia risus nisl sit amet arcu. Donec id tellus eu justo rutrum dictum. Integer tristique risus ut odio rutrum, quis dignissim est varius. Cras a tortor semper, accumsan urna sed, mattis dolor. Ut eget placerat purus. Aliquam in sollicitudin tellus. Vestibulum a semper quam, ut hendrerit enim.</p>
                    <p>Sed et erat consequat, ultrices est quis, sollicitudin lectus. Sed eu semper sapien. Sed suscipit bibendum lacus in semper. Duis mi tellus, gravida a risus id, bibendum tincidunt lectus. Nam consectetur iaculis tempus. Phasellus id consequat felis. Aenean at ipsum molestie, ornare dui in, mollis turpis. Suspendisse sagittis in sapien ac consequat.</p> 
                </div>
                <div id="button">
                    <input type="button" value="Press Me">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel" id="right">
                <div>
                    <h2>Ploc</h2>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <textarea></textarea>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="button" value="Press Me">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The fact is... I don't have a predefined height, for *lorem ipsum* :)

Comment: what is known/predefined? You mention the title, button, and panel? What are they relative to?

Comment: @TheDelta Can we use max-height rather than height for #lorem? and give the value in percentage?

Comment: In terms of height, nothing is known. I don't want to overflow the screen.

Comment: @BharatChoudhary I had some weird results, using height (or max-height) and percent : as if the parent was sized for the full lorem ipsum div, while it [the lorem ipsum div] was scaled.

Comment: Updated as @BharatChoudhary mentioned

Comment: @TheDelta okay, we can change the position to absolute of the button and stick it at the bottom of the page. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: one second, still getting weird results

Comment: I would like to stick the button to the bottom, and fill the remaining space with lorem ipsum, i also had weird results with the absolute attribute, when resizing the page/browser.

Comment: this only stops working like you expect under 600px height. Would that be a problem? Most screens are above 600px

Comment: @Neil Currently, when I run your snippet, I don't need to scroll the whole lorem ipsum div, but I still need to scroll a bit : the main page is affected

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of jquery to identify the dynamic height of the panel.

```js
function resizeElement(id){
  var win= window.outerHeight;
  var title= $("#title").outerHeight();
  var extraPadding= 32;
  var height= win- (title+extraPadding);
  $("#lorem").css("max-height", height+ "px");
}
resizeElement('left');
resizeElement('right');
```

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}

#wrapper {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.panel {
    flex-grow: 1;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 50%;
    padding: 1em;
}
#lorem {
  max-height: 50%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}


/* add colors :) */
body {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

#left {
    background-color: red;
}

#right {
    background-color: purple;
}

#lorem {
    background: yellow;
}

#wrapper {
    background-color: darkblue;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}

h2 {
    background-color: green;
}

input[type=button] {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="panel" id="left">
                <div id="title">
                    <h2>Plic</h2>
                </div>
                <div id="lorem">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec viverra ante sit amet velit rutrum eleifend. Integer efficitur convallis dui, in aliquet augue pellentesque ut. Aenean ut lobortis nibh. Nullam et laoreet arcu, sed consectetur lectus. Phasellus ut nunc orci. Fusce mauris neque, ullamcorper at auctor vel, mollis vitae dolor. Mauris eget eleifend dui. Donec ut vestibulum ex. Nullam laoreet mi ut augue posuere pellentesque. Curabitur aliquet rutrum leo iaculis aliquet. Donec convallis ante nunc, nec dictum ex fringilla sit amet.</p>
                    <p>Nam vel lacus non leo auctor ornare. Integer sit amet lectus in elit tristique eleifend ut a libero. Nam eu mauris in sapien semper venenatis. Integer malesuada fringilla sapien vel blandit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla pretium sem quis nulla efficitur fermentum. Vestibulum leo nisi, imperdiet ut venenatis sed, consectetur cursus purus. Morbi ac ipsum aliquet, tempor enim bibendum, cursus mi. Phasellus eget semper augue, ut viverra tellus. Nulla lacus nisi, congue imperdiet imperdiet sed, sollicitudin eu ex. Ut non dapibus elit. Donec at mollis ante. In aliquet pulvinar sollicitudin. Duis ac orci lobortis, pellentesque lacus in, feugiat urna. Suspendisse consectetur, risus ac elementum condimentum, velit diam convallis ex, id ornare leo arcu at sapien.</p>
                    <p>Donec bibendum elit id orci rutrum, at eleifend urna porttitor. Vivamus odio quam, gravida at euismod in, vestibulum et dui. Morbi egestas urna eu erat hendrerit, in porttitor libero pharetra. Integer justo mauris, pulvinar tincidunt turpis a, tristique ullamcorper nisi. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin mollis tincidunt nunc eget tempor. Mauris bibendum pretium quam id pretium.</p>
                    <p>Phasellus quis nisi vehicula, viverra lacus non, porttitor dui. Suspendisse fringilla ullamcorper finibus. Praesent nec auctor elit. Nulla sit amet risus egestas, lacinia orci feugiat, imperdiet metus. Morbi purus metus, egestas eu massa in, aliquet ullamcorper lectus. Praesent condimentum vehicula condimentum. Morbi nec neque a massa egestas tempus. Donec a cursus dui. Nullam scelerisque ultricies odio a dictum. Proin at ullamcorper justo, non auctor justo. Morbi id nunc id augue pulvinar porttitor. Vestibulum congue magna eu odio condimentum rutrum. Pellentesque non pretium nibh.</p>
                    <p>Nunc ante leo, dapibus sit amet felis id, mattis auctor nisi. Praesent nec lacus posuere, commodo orci in, varius purus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus in euismod nibh, nec congue purus. Aenean euismod laoreet eros, et iaculis mi pharetra vitae. Curabitur eget massa non nibh consectetur pellentesque. In varius pharetra urna, ac tristique sapien lobortis vel.</p>
                    <p>Quisque eu velit mauris. Nunc sit amet placerat tellus. Praesent in fermentum orci. Sed pulvinar facilisis ornare. Vestibulum et metus eget libero tristique vulputate vitae vitae justo. Duis sit amet malesuada dolor. Etiam semper purus id turpis ultrices, eu facilisis purus varius. Vivamus interdum elit ligula, eget condimentum purus tincidunt ac. Nullam at mattis arcu. Nunc vitae mi consequat, hendrerit urna et, gravida nulla. Ut ac purus blandit, volutpat leo non, facilisis lorem. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi dignissim porttitor sem et auctor. Praesent rutrum dignissim orci sit amet euismod.</p>
                    <p>Pellentesque hendrerit, arcu a iaculis semper, nisi libero porta turpis, et suscipit velit ipsum eu eros. Integer ex elit, pretium vel sapien eget, pulvinar sagittis tellus. Etiam non finibus ante, vitae viverra sem. Nulla in purus in lectus varius pulvinar quis non turpis. Suspendisse sit amet arcu orci. Aliquam erat volutpat. Cras tincidunt enim vitae aliquam commodo. Curabitur non justo viverra, porttitor lorem sed, viverra diam.</p>
                    <p>Etiam et lobortis quam. Etiam accumsan pharetra lorem, nec sagittis leo vestibulum nec. Aenean pulvinar nisl ac sapien ultricies, eget lacinia neque aliquet. Fusce egestas libero id nisl rutrum, eget egestas turpis interdum. Etiam consectetur convallis ex. Pellentesque mollis tortor vel dapibus tincidunt. Phasellus varius, nibh non consequat rhoncus, nisi est mollis quam, sed lacinia risus nisl sit amet arcu. Donec id tellus eu justo rutrum dictum. Integer tristique risus ut odio rutrum, quis dignissim est varius. Cras a tortor semper, accumsan urna sed, mattis dolor. Ut eget placerat purus. Aliquam in sollicitudin tellus. Vestibulum a semper quam, ut hendrerit enim.</p>
                    <p>Sed et erat consequat, ultrices est quis, sollicitudin lectus. Sed eu semper sapien. Sed suscipit bibendum lacus in semper. Duis mi tellus, gravida a risus id, bibendum tincidunt lectus. Nam consectetur iaculis tempus. Phasellus id consequat felis. Aenean at ipsum molestie, ornare dui in, mollis turpis. Suspendisse sagittis in sapien ac consequat.</p> 
                </div>
                <div id="footer">
                    <input type="button" value="Press Me 1">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel" id="right">
                <div>
                    <h2>Ploc</h2>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <textarea></textarea>
                </div>
                <div id="footer">
                    <input type="button" value="Press Me 2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It keeps the button at the good place, but the lorem ipsum continues under :/

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted, in your scenario, you need to create a function in jquery which will get the remaining space from window apart from header and bottom, and that height will be given as max-height of  #lorem

Comment: @TheDelta I have created a function using jQuery to resize the max-height, let me know if this works for you!

Comment: I still need to scroll :/

Answer (score 0):

When using flexbox, it's important that you specify exactly what you want for each element. You've said you don't want a height on `#lorem` but you have to specify a height somewhere in order to get the results you want, I specified it with `h1` and `#wrapper`. I believe this is the result you're looking for, take a look at the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f4gty6q2/).

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
h1 {
  height: 20%;
}
#lorem {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.panel {
  padding: 1em;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```