# how to make div take up the rest of the space without overflowing?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs side by side where the red one take up the remaining space
but it overflows when the inside elements are too long like this:

```css
#wrapper{
 width:50%;
display:flex;
height:10rem;
background-color:yellow;
}

#wrapper div{
height:5rem;
}

.second {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div style="background: blue">short version</div>
  <div class="second" style="background:red;">looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooonooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooog version</div>
</div>
```

I tried `overflow-wrap: anywhere;` but there are [browser compatibility issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap#browser_compatibility) plus how do I get it to ellipsis if overflowing at the bottom?

Preferably to look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`overflow-wrap: break-word; min-width:0;` will work.
Another way is to use `word-break: break-all`: https://codepen.io/SergeiMinaev/pen/MWEwvre .

I've also added ellipsis to this example. One thing about ellipsis: the number of the line to which the '...' will be added must be hardcoded, so you'll have to specify fixed height of the container.

**UPD: added the code:**

```css
#wrapper {
  width:300px;
  display:flex;
  height:10rem;
  background-color:yellow;
}
#wrapper div {
  height:4rem;
  /* correct line height is required */
  line-height: 1rem;
}

.second {
  flex: 1;
  word-break: break-all; 
  display: -webkit-box;
  /* maximum number of lines should be hardcoded, sadly */
  -webkit-line-clamp: 4; 
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div style="background: blue">short version</div>
  <div class="second" style="background:red;">
    looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooonooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooog version
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: perfect exactly what I was looking for, could you just add the code in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the value **break-word** of [overflow-wrap](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-wrap/) ?

The [compatibility](https://caniuse.com/?search=overflow-wrap) is good between browser, except for IE of course.

```
.example {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Edit : Flexbox need **min-width:0;** for overflow-wrap to work (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52277368/flexbox-affects-overflow-wrap-behavior)).

Here is the full working code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #wrapper{
                width:50%;
                display:flex;
                height:10rem;
                background-color:yellow;
            }

            #wrapper div{
                height:5rem;
            }

            #wrapper div.second {
                flex: 1;
                overflow-wrap: break-word; /* breaks long words */
                min-width: 0; /* necessary for flexbox */
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
          <div style="background: blue">short version</div>
          <div class="second" style="background:red;">looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooonooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooog version</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you add some code?

Comment: Here is how to code the CSS part :
.example {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

Comment: I tried it, it's not working in the example I've given

Comment: For flexbox you need to add a min-width:0; for the overflow-wrap to work

Comment: looks good! but is it possible to add ellipsis to the ending?

Comment: For multiline ellipsis you'll need to use Javascript. There are multiple examples on Stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404508/cross-browser-multi-line-text-overflow-with-ellipsis-appended-within-a-fixed-wid)

Answer (score 0):

You can use overflow: hidden; in css like so :

```css
#wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is the full code :

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#wrapper div {
  height: 5rem;
}

.second {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div style="background: blue">short version</div>
  <div class="second" style="background:red;">looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooonooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooog version</div>
</div>
```